# Google Voice API

Tags: python, voice

Is there a way to extract the text of a transcribed voicemail using pygooglevoice? Printing the message simply prints the filename.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, according to [the pygooglevoice docs](http://sphinxdoc.github.com/pygooglevoice/index.html), the Python binding for the Google Voice API doesn't have any methods to get the text of a transcribed voicemail. However, the project is only on version 0.5, and you can make a feature request (if one hasn't already been made).

You can also always contribute your own implementation of this behavior to pygooglevoice.

Sorry, I wish such a behavior existed, but it doesn't. You may be able to use other means (e.g. cURL, HTML/XML parsing, etc.) to achieve what you want to do but it's not in pygooglevoice.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible to achieve this with the XMLParser helper function in googlevoice? If so, is there any documentation on how to go about doing this?

Comment: @Ridman: I'm not sure, it depends on how Google Voice represents these transcripts, and I don't really have any way of finding that out ATM. I tried the XMLParser and had little luck, but I hardly know what I'm doing when it comes to XML. Your best bet is to inspect the XML yourself and see if what you need is in there, and then parse the XML using one of Python's XML libraries.